# Get checked checkboxes values per cell in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table data with 3 check-boxes in last column. I just wanted the values of selected check-boxes by clicking in that cell or by checking/ unchecking the checkbox.
Below is the structure I have tried.

HTML-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Promoted" value="Promoted" id="promo_" 
 >Promoted

<input type="checkbox" name="Professional"  value="Professional" id="prof_">Professional

<input type="checkbox" name="Amateur"  value="Amateur" id="amat_">Amateur
```

jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#table1 tr').click(function (event){

        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');    

        var selected = $("#myOption_1 input:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.name;}).get();
        var data1 = (" \"" + selected.join(";") + "\"");
        alert(data1);
});
});
```

where table1 is table- id and myOption_1 is  id which gets incremented.

What i need is by checking the checkbox I need only the checked checkbox values in the particular cell only.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the click handler refers to the clicked `tr` so you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to filter only input elements within that `tr`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table1 tr').click(function (event) {
        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var selected = $(this).find("input:checked").map(function (i, el) {
            return el.name;
        }).get();
        var data1 = ('"' + selected.join(";") + '"');
        alert(data1);
    });
});
```

if you want to target only the last cell in the tr then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table1 td:last-child').click(function (event) {
        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var selected = $(this).find("input:checked").map(function (i, el) {
            return el.name;
        }).get();
        var data1 = ('"' + selected.join(";") + '"');
        alert(data1);
    });
});
```